# how to make onclick event when clicking the date from datepicker UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

hi guys i have try to make a select data function with jquery with onclick event that have triggering the date from datepicker.
i have try to make a code but seems not work at all.

this is the textboxt id's that contain the datepicker call function. `$(#date)`
i have try to make a code for selecting my data. 
this is the code.

```js
$(document).on('click','#date',function(e) {
 var data = $("#form_input10").serialize();
   
 $('#table_s tbody').empty();
        $.ajax({
   data: data,
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/termocouple/get_date.php",
            success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
 $('#date1').val((list[i]['tanggal2']));
  }
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the condition when the datepicker running is like this. when the textbox clicked then the datepicker will be showing. nah when i use my code, the condition like this the 1st click is for show the datepicker that ( from this condition the textbox doesn't have any value of the date) the the datepicker showing and i select the date. i need do one click again on the textbox for showing my data.

please someone help me to solve this
please

Comment: The UI Datepicker has a number of built in events and methods, did you look at the documentation at all?

Comment: @adeneo yeah i have do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a click event on the datepicker, you'd want to use one of the datepicker's available options. One is beforeShow, and allows you to have a function run before the datepicker opens up:

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({   
     beforeShow: doThatThing
});

function doThatThing(){  
    var data = $("#form_input10").serialize();
    $('#table_s tbody').empty();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "Post",
        url: "../php/termocouple/get_date.php",
        success: function(data){
          var list = JSON.parse(data);
          for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            $('#date1').val((list[i]['tanggal2']));
          }
        }
    });
}
```